# Need to copy Order.id to multiples line_items.order_id after create order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So, this is how this things works..

1. the client opens the browser, a cart is created in seesion and in DB and he starts to browse the products. (creates Cart)
2. he adds products to cart  (creates line_items)
3. he press the checkout button and the order is created (creates order)

if the order is successfully created (check by paypal gateway) then the browser redirects user to products page and the cart is destroyed. (the code will say it better)

**Orders_Controller**

```
def create
    @order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
    @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    if @order.save
      if @order.purchase
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
      else
        render :action => "failure"
      end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_path, :notice => 
          'Thank you for your order.' }
          format.json { render :json => @order }
        end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

line_items stays in the database cause I want to display the Order in admin panel and the line_items for this order and I would do so if I could save the order.id into line_items.order_id.

Now when I fill up the form for new order and I press the send button, I have NULL value for all line_items.order_id fields but I need to have the order.id in it

here is the **order** table screen shot

[image]

and the **line_items**

[image]

as you can see now  the order_id in line_items is equal to  id from order (40) but it is so because I manually inserted the order_id to line_items for testing purposes. Normally I get the NULL value instead of order_id

I just don't get it how to insert this order.id to line_items after the order is saved

I could explain my idea here, but only in words as I see it, I don't know how to code this in rails:

so, after the order is created, the app must look for line_items that has the same cart_id as the order that was saved (as both have cart_id field in tables) and for all line_items that has the same cart_id as order, change order_id = order.id. This is how I see it. If there is another way please let me know. Thank you.

p.s. if any code is missgin I'll update it as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `current_cart.build_order` isn't assigning the Cart's LineItems to the Order when it's created. You could probably just add `@order.line_items = current_cart.line_items` after the line with `.build_order`. Then when the Order was saved, the LineItems would be associated with it.

Comment: Yes man!!! many kisses!! :)) don't get me wrong.. I am just happy I made it. Thank you.